# Is there a library of example display templates?

Tags: display-template, cswp

The standard sharepoint display templates for the CSWP are very limited. I would assume that someone has already made and shared some display templates for general document searches.

Are there any websites that host these template?

Answer (score 2):

Google Search for 'Pnp Display Templates' or [SPCSR](https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates) by Elio Struyf

It is unknown what the future of Display Templates is going to be with all the new SharePoint Fx / SharePoint Framework / New Experience developments at Microsoft.

Expect more news closer to the Ignite conference (**sept 26-30 2016**)

No harm done if it is killed (but available for Classic experiences) The Microsoft Engineer who came up with mixing JavaScript in HTML comments should be forced to work with MSDOS 1.0 for the rest of his IT career.